# How to look up parameter name of django 'custom template tag' argument

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I created **custom template tag**, which has **lots of parameters**:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('components/mail_button.html', takes_context=True)
def mail_button(context, button_content, button_name, button_link, button_width=265, button_height=47, background_color=COLOR_WHITE, margin_bottom=MARGIN_M):
    return {
        'button_content': button_content,
        'button_name': button_name,
        'button_link': button_link,
        'button_width': button_width,
        'button_height': button_height,
        'background_color': background_color,
        'margin_bottom': margin_bottom,
        'site': context['site'],
        'LANGUAGE_CODE': context['LANGUAGE_CODE']
    }
```

Then in my template, I put my custom template tag with proper arguments.

```
{% mail_image 'mail-image-content-animated.jpg' 432 524 'Augmented Reality App' '#ECF0F1' %}
```

The question is, when using **PyCharm**, how can I possibly **look up the parameter name**, without navigating to my templatetags/mailing_tags.py ( (cmnd/ctrl + click)?

If it is at all possible, I'd be grateful for an answer. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was pretty easy. In order to lookup all the custom-template-tag's parameter names, you just need to hover over custom-template-tag, press ctrl/cmmnd, and wait till the popup with all the details appears. Nice one!